# Access image from array swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an image gallery in swift and I want to create a label under it that displays the image title.In my code, I have created An array that stores all the images and I want. And I want to create an `if` statement that when a certain image is displayed I want the text of the label to change.I am not sure how to access the certain image that is being displayed in the scroll view.

Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mainscrollview: UIScrollView!
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainscrollview.frame = view.frame
        imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goku"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boruto"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tail"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sage"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tobi")]

        for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = imageArray[i]
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainscrollview.frame.width,height: self.mainscrollview.frame.height)
            mainscrollview.contentSize.width = mainscrollview.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            mainscrollview.addSubview(imageView)



        }


    }
```

***However the line***

```
if imageView.image = UIImageView.init(image: "goku")  {


            }
```

Gives Me a bunch of Errors

### Pseudo Code

```
if image == "goku" && image_is_displayed_on_screen == true {
label.text = "GOKU";
}
```

Comment: Please include the errors in your question. However, one of the issues is that you are trying to use _assignment (=)_ instead of _comparison(==)_. Unrelated, but you shouldn't call `init` explicitly, just use the shorthand notation, `UIImageView(image: "")`. Also, `UIImageView.init(image: "goku")` cannot work, since `"goku"` is a `String`, not `UIImage`.

Comment: How do I get the image that is currently displayed on the screen

Comment: You should already have that stored as a variable of type `UIImage`, just check whether `imageView.image` equals that or not. Something like `let gokuImage = UIImage(named: "goku")`, then `if imageView.image == gokuImage` assuming the image is stored in your app bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `image` property of you imageView is a `UIImage` object not a `UIImageView`.

Try:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "goku")
```

Comment: You also have to use `==` for comparison, not `=`.

Comment: Thank You, this has worked however I've run into a problem when the image changes the title doesn't change

Comment: Hi  the image changes the title doesn't change even if i set the if statement

Answer (score 1):

There is a property for uiimage to get the image by name.

Your code must look like as below

```
 if imageView.image ==  UIImage(named:"goku")  {


 }
```

One more point, you have written & added image in array as below

```
imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "goku"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "boruto"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tail"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sage"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tobi")]
```

Don't do this, only add image name (string) in your array and in for loop get the image by image name.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't set a UIImageView to `image` property.

Comment: Moreover, you shouldn't be calling the `init` method explicitly, use the shorthand notation. And your code won't even compile, since you are using assignment instead of comparison...

Answer (score 1):

Comparing images using `==` may or may not work as expected. I'm pretty sure that that will return false unless both sides of the comparison contain the same exact object, not 2 copies of the same object.

In any case it's inefficient to load another copy of an image into memory just to see if it matches.

I would suggest saving an array of image names, creating a subclass of UIImageView that has a name property, and installing that into each image view you install in your scroll view. Then compare image names, not images.

Comment: Can you give me an example of saving an array of image names, creating a subclass of UIImageView that has a name property, and installing that into each image view you install in the scroll view?

Comment: When I compare the image names the tile doesn't change it only stays as one.

Comment: This is pretty simple stuff. Attempt it yourself and if you are unable to get it working post your code and we can help you fix it.